# Looking to understand MLE and mle

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I'm presently in Computational Statistics.  I'm struggling a bit with truly understanding the concept of *Estimators* and *Estimates*.  I understand the difference on a simple level: one is a function to use to generate estimates.  In other words, an estimate is a single value such as $\hat{\theta}$ as opposed to the actual value $\theta$.  I've taken Statistics and must admit to not fully grasping the topic at that time.

I have this homework problem: Given observations $Y_1,...,Y_n$ are described by the relationship $Y_i = \theta x^2 + \epsilon_i$, where $x_i,...,x_n$ are fixed constants (observed values) and $\epsilon_i,...,\epsilon_n$ are i.i.d. $N(\theta, \sigma^2)$.

I'm asked to first find the *least squares estimator* of this.  I do not fully understand what I'm truly being asked to do.  The textbook, Computational Statistics by Givens and Hoeting, seems to interchangeably use the terms *estimator* and *estimate*.  I see that, because these are individual and independently distributed, the Likelihood function is the product of the p.d.f.  But now enters my lack of understanding.  How are the *Estimators* tied or linked to the likelihood functions?  What is it I'm really calculating?

When I took *Foundations of Analysis*, the author of that textbook stated that most students have difficulty with topics until they have full "internalized" them.  I think this is my struggle with this: internalization.  What is it that I'm truly being asked to do?

Comment: The method of MLE and the method of least squares are different concepts, I think.

Comment: If you are asked to find the least squares estimator, then you must have been introduced to the method of [least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Problem_statement).

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes, I have been introduced to it.  I have found the notation of statistics to something of a confusing issue.  Not necessarily when in typed media: $X$ being a random variable and $x$ a realized value of $X$.  But when writing ... that's something else, they look very much the same.  Further, the MLE vs. the mle, hasn't been fully clear.  The book we're using leaves me guessing sometimes.  I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Suggest you take a look at a standard textbook on mathematical statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give a formal definition of these notions. Let $X$ be an observed random element with values in a measurable space $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{H})$ ($\mathcal{X}$ is called the *sampling space*). Let $\{P_{\theta}:\theta\in\Theta\}$ be a family of probability measures on $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{H})$; typically $\Theta$ is  subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. We assume that the distribution of $X$ is $P_{\theta}$ for some unknown $\theta$. Given a realization $x$ of $X$, one wants to estimate the unknown parameter $\theta$.

A measurable function $T:(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{H})\to (\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{G})$ is called a *statistic*. When $\mathcal{Y}=\Theta$, the statistic $T$ becomes an *estimator*. The random variable $T(X)$ is also referred to as an estimator of $\theta$. For a specific realization $x$ of $X$ one obtains an *estimate* $T(x)$.

---

In your case the observed random element is $X=\{(Y_i,x_i)\}_{i=1}^n$. The least squares estimator of $\theta$ is given by
$$
T(X)=\underset{b\in \Theta}{\operatorname{argmin}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-bx_i^2)^2\right).
$$

Comment: As I am reading through your explanation, it sounds as though an _estimator_ isn't a function at all.  I thought that an estimator _returns_ an estimate.

Comment: It is a function of $X$.